# how to use cmd inside a Dockerfile to compile a file

Tags: docker

What I want:
i want to run a cpp file witch use opencv inside a container

What I've done:

installing an image of opencv:

```
 docker pull spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
```

create a docker file

```
FROM spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv

COPY . .  

CMD ["g++ a.cpp a.out"] 

CMD ["./a.out"]
```

bash command

sudo docker build -t project_opencv . #OK
sudo docker run -p 80:80 -it project_opencv

Error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "g++ a.cpp a.out": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
> ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled

Answer (score 1):

CMD is supposed to be the entrypoint for the container.

You are looking for [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run)