# how to use a executable file created in a docker file in the same docker file

Tags: docker

What I want: i want to run a cpp file witch use opencv inside a container

What I've done:

installing an image of opencv:

```
docker pull spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
```

create a docker file

```
FROM spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
RUN ["g++ a.cpp -o a.out"]
COPY . .
CMD ["./a.out"]
```

bash command

```
sudo docker build -t project_opencv
```

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "g++ a.cpp -o a.out": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

first I try this with cmd instead of RUN ([how to use cmd inside a Dockerfile to compile a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866393/how-to-use-cmd-inside-a-dockerfile-to-compile-a-file)). It couldn't find a.out although I've done COPY . .
Now it seems that there is a problem to create a.out

Answer (score 1):

When you use the JSON-array form of `RUN` (or `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`), you explicitly provide the set of "words" that make up the command.  As you've shown it, it is a single word, and Docker tries to run it as such, including the spaces in the command name it's looking up.  You need to split it into its constituent words yourself.

```
RUN ["g++", "a.cpp", "-o", "a.out"]
```

The reverse side of this is that there is no splitting, expansion, or interpolation that happens in this command:

```
# Preserves both the literal $ and the spaces
RUN ["cp", "dollars-word-$word.txt", "file name with spaces.txt"]
```

Especially for `RUN` it's common to use the shell form.  This wraps the command in `sh -c` so it works like an ordinary command.  (There are technical reasons you might not want this for `CMD` and especially `ENTRYPOINT`.)

```
RUN g++ a.cpp -o a.out
RUN cp dollars-word-\$word.txt, 'file name with spaces.txt'
RUN tail env-var-$word.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy your a.cpp into docker image then your RUN command will work , I am not sure about your RUN ["g++ a.cpp -o a.out"] command this will work or not but try this:

```
FROM spmallick/opencv-docker:opencv
COPY . .
RUN ["g++ a.cpp -o a.out"] 
CMD ["./a.out"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the permissions for the files you have copied, from your host machine into the container.

You could also check the directory you are in, and if you need to change the directory, then you can use the `WORKDIR` command in your Dockerfile.

It would also be useful to start a bash session in the container, and run the commands manually. For each successful command, you can enter the command into the Dockerfile, or if you encounter an error, you can also troubleshoot more easily, rather than change the Dockerfile each time and run, and if you need to debug which is time consuming.